# Does JVM applies any default compression to jar and war files

Tags: java, jar, jvm, compression

Does a jar/war file created by jvm after building a project compressed?

If Yes, Which compression technique is used by default? and is there any performance degradation of compression?

If No, Why not ?

Answer (score 2):

Its not JVM, but *jar* utility that is used for creating jar/war packages. Its built upon **ZIP file format**. Of course, when the package has to read, it requires unarchiving. This is a **one time activity**, and thus has *negligible* performance considerations.